# chainerのNStepBiLSTMのdropoutについて

Tags: python3, chainer

chainerのNStepBiLSTMにはdropout率の引数があると思いますが、

0 → 全くdropoutしない
1 → 全て0になる
になるのでしょうか？

dropout=0としたところうまく動かなかったので、もしかして逆なのでは？と思って質問しました。

下のコードのdropout=args.dropoutのところです。

```
L.NStepBiLSTM(n_layers=args.layers, in_size=100,\
                  out_size=args.hidden_size,dropout=args.dropout)
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/133260

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/functions/noise/dropout.py

上記chainerのgithubソースコード上のdropout関数の引数であるratioは
デフォルト値0.5なので、「残る」のが50%と捉えても、「棄てる」のが50%と捉えても
矛盾がないため、私もしばしばどちらの意味だったのか忘れてしまいますが……

同ソースコード上のDropoutクラスのコンストラクタ引数にあたるdropout_ratioは、
名前からして、「棄てる割合」であると覚えると、覚えやすいです。
（そしてdropout関数のratioは、そのままDropoutクラスのdropout_ratioへと渡されます）

実際、以下の2行がありまして、

scale = x[0].dtype.type(1. / (1 - self.dropout_ratio))
flag = numpy.random.rand(*x[0].shape) >= self.dropout_ratio

どちらの行からも「棄てる割合」であることが読み取れます。
（読み取れませんか？　いえ、前後も含めれば読み取れますよね……？）

https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/functions/connection/n_step_rnn.py

NStepBiLSTMのコンストラクタ引数であるdropoutは辿っていくと
NStepRNNBaseのコンストラクタ引数を経て、
上記chainerのgithubソースコード上のn_step_rnn関数上にて
dropout_ratioという引数にそのまま渡され、
その先では前述のdropout関数へとそのまま渡されます。

通りかかっただけではありますし、2ヶ月も前のご質問ではある様ですが、
他に回答している方もいなかったため、ご回答しておきました。

> dropout=0としたところうまく動かなかったので、もしかして逆なのでは？と思って質問しました。

なお、逆にdropout=1としてしまうと全て棄てることになり、むしろ動かないはずです。

ドロップアウト率は通常0.5が一般的とされますが、入り口付近では0.2だとか、
ある程度深い層では0.7付近でもよかったりします。
（ただ、n_step_rnn系の場合、設定箇所が1箇所しかない様ではありますが……）

何も見ずに無難なところで設定するなら0.5はベターだと思いますが、
色々変えてみると良いかと思います。